# How can I accept default parameter in function when 'None' or no argument is passed?

Tags: python, function, default-parameters

I am writing a new python class with a generic function. At one point I have a requirement as follows

```
def function(a=1):
    ....
    ....
    print a # here I want a to be 1 if None or nothing is passed
```

Eg:

- a(None) should print 1
- a() should print 1
- a(2) should print 2

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function with a default argument, later you can check for the value passed and print it:

```
def fun(a=1):
    a = 1 if a is None else a
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def function(a=1):
    if a is None:
        a = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Should use None as default parameter.

```
def function(a=None):
    if a == None:
        a = 1
    print a
```

Otherwise you'll run into problems when calling the function multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling the function multiple times"? What kind of problems?

Comment: I suppose the problem mostly arises with mutable data types.  Here's a link that explains it nicely:  [link](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def function(a=1):
...     print(a if a else 1)
... 
>>> function(None)
1
>>> function(2)
2
>>> function(1)
1
>>> function(123)
123
>>> function(0)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(a=1):
    print(1 if a is None else a)

function()
function(None)
function(2)
function(0)
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
0
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value you specify is going to be used only if you do not pass the value when calling the function at all. If you specified it as `a=1` then calling it with zero arguments would indeed use `1` as the default value, but calling it with `None` will just put `None` to `a`.

When I want to give the `None` and "not specified at all" cases the same meaning, I do this:

```
def function(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = 1
    ...
```

This way it will work as you want. Also, compared to the other solutions like

```
def function(a=1):
    if a is None:
        a = 1
    ...
```

you specify the "default" value (the `1`) only once.